# How to capture HEAP [ new.win32.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 002C0000, 02E43AA8 )

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

i try to capture in visual studio 2012 express Invalid address
in very simple code , how can i capture it . 
This is what im getting when trying to run the code :

```
HEAP[match2_new.win32.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 002C0000, 02E43AA8 )
match2_new.win32.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
```

this is the stack:

```
    msvcr110d.dll!_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(const void * pUserData) Line 2036  C++
    msvcr110d.dll!_free_dbg_nolock(void * pUserData, int nBlockUse) Line 1322   C++
    msvcr110d.dll!_free_dbg(void * pUserData, int nBlockUse) Line 1265  C++
    msvcr110d.dll!operator delete(void * pUserData) Line 54 C++
    match2_new.win32.exe!std::allocator<std::_Container_proxy>::deallocate(std::_Container_proxy * _Ptr, unsigned int __formal) Line 586    C++
    match2_new.win32.exe!std::_String_alloc<0,std::_String_base_types<char,std::allocator<char> > >::_Free_proxy() Line 683 C++
    match2_new.win32.exe!std::_String_alloc<0,std::_String_base_types<char,std::allocator<char> > >::~_String_alloc<0,std::_String_base_types<char,std::allocator<char> > >() Line 656  C++
    match2_new.win32.exe!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >() Line 965  C++
>   match2_new.win32.exe!GameController::setGemsInBoard(int levlnumber) Line 98 C++
    match2_new.win32.exe!GameLayer::startGame() Line 53 C++
    match2_new.win32.exe!GameScene::init() Line 43  C++
    match2_new.win32.exe!GameScene::create() Line 24    C++
    match2_new.win32.exe!GameScene::scene() Line 19 C++
    match2_new.win32.exe!AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() Line 109  C++
    libcocos2d.dll!cocos2d::CCApplication::run() Line 47    C++
    match2_new.win32.exe!wWinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInstance, wchar_t * lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) Line 34  C++
    match2_new.win32.exe!__tmainCRTStartup() Line 528   C
    match2_new.win32.exe!wWinMainCRTStartup() Line 377  C
```

simple code :

```
void GameController::setGemsInBoard(int levlnumber)
{

    switch (levlnumber)
    {
    case 1:
         {
             std::string level_1 = "00011000,00111100,01111110,01111110,01111110,01111110,00111100,00011000";
           fillBoardArray(level_1);
             break;
         }
    case 2:
         {
             std::string level_2 = "00011000,00011000,11111111,11111111,11111111,00111100,00011000,00011000";
             fillBoardArray(level_2);
             break;
         }
    default:
        break;
    }


}
```

**update** :

```
void fillBoardArray(std::string lvlstr);


void GameController::fillBoardArray(std::string lvlstr)
{
   // CCLOG("fillBoardArray");
    int irow=0;
    int icol=0;
    for(int i=0;i<lvlstr.size();i++)
    {
        if(lvlstr[i]=='0')
        {
            m_GemBoardPositionMap[irow][icol] = 0;
            icol++;
        }
        else if(lvlstr[i]=='1')
        {
            m_GemBoardPositionMap[irow][icol] = 1;
            icol++;
        }
        else if(lvlstr[i]==',')
        {
            irow++;
            icol=0;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: post the code of `fillBoardArray(level_1)` or at very least it's signature. The error clearly indicates that you're corrupting the std::String between the ctor and dtor, and the only place for this to happen is inside the fillBoardArray function, which is missing.

Comment: here i put the code , this driving me crazy

Comment: You have no bounds check on `irow` and `icol`. If they go out of range, you will corrupt memory. Perhaps `m_GemBoardPositionMap` is not properly initialized.

Comment: Look in your code for double deletes or places where you can step outside of the allocated range of memory like accessing index -1 of an array allocated on the heap.

Comment: Your program is corrupting the heap.  That happens early so there's not that much code to check.  The m_GemBoardPositionMap indexing is certainly a good candidate, you never check if icol and irow are valid indices.  Or the bug is located in code we just can't see.

Comment: how can i check this in the code with the compiler giving me hint
where to check ? 
is there some tools to do this , this is impossible to start to go line by line

Comment: @user63898: It is certainly not impossible to verify that each line makes valid assumptions about the memory locations its writing. That said, there are tools trying to capturing of bounds access earlier, e.g., [purify](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/us/en/rational-purify-family/) and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Whether the tool can successfully determine out of bounds accesses depends on how much information it gets on the memory segments being used.

Comment: ok thanks i found the problem !!! 
the m_GemBoardPositionMap was init with CONSTANTS i changed to 1 on each array ,